# Change div content - ads bottom / top

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

The ads from a website are placed at the bottom of the source but should be visible on top.

The ad placeholder:

```
<div id="300_250_placeholder"></div>
```

The add code:

```
<div id="300_250">
<script>AdShow("300_250");</script>
</div>
```

Task: The add code should "only" be visible in the placeholder and not in the original div.

What I tried without success:

```
$(300_250).append(300_250_placeholder);
```

thank you.

Comment: look at [jquery ID selector](http://api.jquery.com/id-selector/)

Comment: Sounds like a homework assignment,

Comment: That's one reason you shouldn't use IDs starting with number, here it would works as expected although you'd have better to use ID selector as string:  http://jsfiddle.net/wjvynz5f/  or referring to window property explecitely http://jsfiddle.net/wjvynz5f/1/

Answer (score 0):

use this to add your result to the top of div

```
$("#YourDivId").prepend("YourContent");
```

Comment: @user2057781 is that what you mean ?

Comment: this works when it its just a word or a image but not when I have to use javascript. 

    $('#d300_600_z2_placeholder').prepend('<script>AdShow("300_600_z2");</script>')